# How can I write both endpoints and socket codes in the same project? Node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, chat, endpoint

I have a project with endpoints, for example as follows:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const port = 5000;

...
app.post()
...

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}.`);
});
```

I'm trying to add the socket codes below to this node.js project above, but it doesn't work at all.

````js
const SocketServer = require('websocket').server
const http = require('http')

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {})

server.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Listening on port 3000...")
})

wsServer = new SocketServer({httpServer:server})

const connections = []

wsServer.on('request', (req) => {
    const connection = req.accept()
    console.log('new connection')
    connections.push(connection)

    connection.on('message', (mes) => {
        connections.forEach(element => {
            if (element != connection)
                element.sendUTF(mes.utf8Data)
        })
    })

    connection.on('close', (resCode, des) => {
        console.log('connection closed')
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(connection), 1)
    })

})```
````

It works separately in 2 codes, but when combined, the server gives 503 error and nothing works?  the purpose of the project is to run both the endpoints and the websocket at once. how can i combine these 2 codes and get it working?
*What I tried: I wrote above app.list, I wrote separately under app.list but I got 503 error every time* (Can we run the two of them properly without mixing them together? I couldn't find anything on this site about this issue.)